# Firefox 63 with containers on Fedora: GMail keeps logging out

Tags: firefox, fedora, gmail, firefox-extensions

[Copied from StackOverflow, as inappropriate there]

I'm using Firefox 63.0.3 on Fedora 27, and started using the 'containers' functionality a few weeks ago to segregate my work tabs from my personal ones.

Mostly, it works well -- but for some reason, my Google sessions (GMail Drive, whatever) keep getting logged out after what feels like 1-2 hours.

I need to collect more info, but so far I haven't found anything online mentioning, much less explaining, this. And it has happened on two separate laptops, including a newly-provisioned one.

Has anyone else seen this or know of a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be due to an unexpected extension interaction. Fixed that, and the problem went away. Derrr.